# Hosting kml files on public webserver

Tags: kml

I want to display a kml layer in google maps,for that i have to host the kml file in a webserver. I want to get the url of actual kml file for doing this. I've created a kml file and I've hosted it in public webserver. I'm new to this and I want the url of the actual kml file and not the download url for the kml file. How to get the url of the actual kml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropbox and Google Drive, for example, hide the actual URL so you have to find the "share" options or download options which will help you find the URL to the actual KML content. Clicking on the file often displays a preview HTML page with information about the file not the file itself.

For example, uploading a KML file to Google Drive (aka Google Docs) stores your KML. You can then click on the file name in the list of files which popups up a dialog with a download button. After you download it, the URL should be recorded in the download history of your web browser.

Other public web servers would have similar mechanisms to access the actual file. Note that some web servers may not return the correct media type for KML files which may cause problems.

Comment: thanks for the info. I am struggling to get this to work. I've uploaded my PNG file for my overlay and I've made the file public to everyone. I have used the shareable link from Google Drive and pasted this into the sample code provided [here](https://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/screenoverlays.html)  and it's still not working. Is there an alternative way to share KML/PNG files?

Comment: Try creating a KMZ file with the png file included in that KMZ with a local reference to it then it will be self-contained. Then should work in Google Earth or wherever.

Answer (score 1):

Obtain the shareable link of your file. Record the `ID`. Then change the shareable link into:

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=YOUR_FILE_ID&amp;export=kml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without hosting it yourself.

If you upload it to onedrive and share it, you can make it "public to anyone who has link".

Once you have done that if you download it, go to your downloads on browser, right click the download and select "copy download link".

This link can be used just like any public .kml link.

An example of it being added onto an existing google map.

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=1_Helloj1pktXP7IHwWmShBlLXCoHyo9BN&forcekml=1',
      map: map
  });
```